snowflake - clone table based on a large table sql query results?
can we use the like statement to clone results part of a sql query?
I have a large table A. i want to query only 5% sample of that and store the results in table B(preferably a clone with zero storage). can that work?

In Snowflake, cloning a table creates a full copy, including all its data and metadata. Unfortunately, Snowflake does not natively support cloning just a subset of a table's data directly.
If you're looking for a solution that minimizes storage, you might consider the following approaches, depending on your use case:
1. Clone a Subset Table

Create a new subset table using a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT query.
Clone this subset table. Note that cloning might not be necessary if your primary goal is performance enhancement.

2. Create a Dynamic Table Using a LIKE Query

Create a dynamic table using a LIKE query. The advantage of this approach is that the table will auto-refresh based on the specified tag interval.

3. Create a Logical View Over a Large Table

If the table is well-clustered, a logical view can be created with clustering keys. This approach can be efficient and avoid the need for separate storage.

